# How to set a static height and width for a UIImageView in xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, custom-renderer

So i'm working on a CustomRenderer for a Picker in which i need an image to the right side of the picker, i was able to do that, but the image size is too big, how can i set a static size to it,

i tried doing this, but i'm not sure if i'm on the right track

```
 Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
                var downarrow = UIImage.FromBundle(element.PickerImageSource);
                Control.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
                var imgView = new UIImageView(downarrow);
                imgView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
                Control.RightView = imgView;
```

any inputs would be helpful
[image]

Comment: Did you tried updating your CGRect parameters? like `new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0.1, 0.1, 20, 20);`

Comment: nope nothing changed @Dishant

Comment: @Venky Hi, have a try with setting `ContentMode` for `UIImageView` to check whether it works. Such as: `imgView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;`

Comment: that helped @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: @Venky Glad be helpful! If so, would you mind I update this as the answer?

Comment: yes indeed @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: @Venky Okey, I have updated an answer. Please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [ContentMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiviewcontentmode?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) property of **UIImageView**

> Controls how the cached bitmap of a view must be rendered when the view's bounds change.

And from the **[ContentMode Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiviewcontentmode?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)**, there is a `ScaleAspectFit` to make the image fits the frame of UIImageView.

> Scales the contents so that everything is visible, while preserving the aspect ration. Any areas that are not filled become transparent.

Therefore, you can modify code by adding this property:

```
Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
var downarrow = UIImage.FromBundle(element.PickerImageSource);
Control.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
var imgView = new UIImageView(downarrow);
imgView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1);

// modify here
imgView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;

Control.RightView = imgView;
```

Comment: This is only working prior iOS v13

Answer (score 1):

UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit did not work for me... However, I came up with another solution:

```
var template = new UIView();
template.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 20, 20);

var image = new UIImageView();
image.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
image.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("ic_caret_down");
template.AddSubview(image);

Control.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
Control.RightView = template;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for iOS 13+. Starting in iOS 13, the implementation of leftViewRect(forBounds:) and rightViewRect(forBounds:) now ask the view for its systemLayoutSizeFitting(:). To achieve the previous behavior when linking against and running on iOS 13, add explicit sizing constraints on the view, wrap it in a plain UIView.